tkinter image collecter by garbage collector python
I'm trying to display a PIL image that i converted to tkImage inside a function of my main class representing my application.But i keep having the error corresponding to the suppression of my tkImage by the garbage collector of python.
I tried to make my tkImage from local to global(self) but it changes nothing and i cannot find solution apart form this one which seems to not be working.
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import Menu, filedialog
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

class MainApplication:
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        self.root.title("Application avec Canevas et Graphiques")
        self.photo_image = None  # Initialisation de l'attribut pour stocker l'image

        self.create_menu()
        self.create_canvas()

    def create_menu(self):
        menubar = Menu(self.root)
        self.root.config(menu=menubar)
        
        file_menu = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
        file_menu.add_command(label="Open", command=self.open_image)
        file_menu.add_command(label="Save")
        file_menu.add_separator()
        file_menu.add_command(label="Exit", command=self.root.quit)
        menubar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=file_menu)

    def open_image(self):
        filetypes = [
            ("Image files", "*.jpg;*.png;*.gif;*.bmp"),
            ("All files", "*.*")
        ]
        image_ini_path = filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=filetypes)
        if image_ini_path:
            # Ouvrir l'image avec PIL
            image = Image.open(image_ini_path)
            
            # Convertir l'image en PhotoImage pour Tkinter
            self.photo_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)

            # Effacer le canevas avant d'afficher la nouvelle image
            self.canvas.delete("all")

            # Afficher l'image sur le canevas
            self.canvas.create_image(0, 0, image=self.photo_image, anchor='nw')

    def create_canvas(self):
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self.root, width=800, height=600, bg="white")
        self.canvas.pack(expand=True, fill=tk.BOTH)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = MainApplication(root)
    root.mainloop()



When I run your code the image shows up in the window. Can you show what error you are getting? I see nothing wrong with the code you posted. I had to modify the filetypes, but that seems unrelated to the question you're asking.

When I run (on spyder) the image doesn't show up in the window and i  have the error tkinter.TclError: image "pyimage3" doesn't exist

I can run your code from Spyder and load a picture without any issues. I have Spyder 5.5.5 | Python 3.12.4 64-bit | Qt 5.15.13 | PyQt5 5.15.10 | IPython 8.26.0 in linux.

I have python 3.11 and Spyder 5.4.3 on windows(Anaconda 2.6.1) and i always get the error: _tkinter.TclError: image "pyimage1" doesn't exist

Ok I uninstalled anaconda and reinstalled it and it works. Don't know why tho.
